# Seeking world map with boundaries of regions and communities for commercial use?

Tags: data

I am looking for a vector file worldmap which should include as many boundaries reaching to a very small level (like ZIP-Codes/small communities/etc) as possible.

The data of Natural Earth is quite good, but does not go that much in detail. The [GADM](http://www.gadm.org) data would be nearly perfect, but it is not allowed for company use.

Requirements:

- Consistent boundaries for nearby countries (no overlapping!).
- As much detail as possible (refering to boundaries).
- Country boundaries and subdivisions should be separated.
- The data is for **company use**, therefore I should be able to buy it, or it should be free to use for companies.

I also thought of extracting it from the OpenStreetMap data. Do you think this is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also the Global Administrative Unit Layers (GAUL) from [FAO](http://fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/metadata.show?id=12691) , same has the GADM data (there is somehow a permission that can be requested).

Another source you can look at are the GIS Data Vendors from GPS companies:

- [navteq](http://www.navteq.com/customers_coverage.htm)
- [tele atlas](http://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/licensing/?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&siteId=TeleAtlasCW1&siteRelativeUrl=%252F&ssUrlPrefix=/)

They use that kind of data as well, but I am not sure if they can sell it back to you and also the price they will charge.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest to have a look at TomTom offer. I've used their [MultiNet](http://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/licensing/products/maps/multinet/) product. This dataset is mainly developed with navigation in mind, but some of the layers provided cover administrative division and zip code areas.

> At least 10 levels of Administrative Orders are defined for each
>   country. The highest  level, Order 0, is always the Country, which is
>   made up of all lower-level units. Order 8 is also always present. The
>   name of this level and the extension of its units are country
>   dependent. Order 8 is the lowest level that covers the whole territory
>   of the country ([source](http://agi.s3.amazonaws.com/geodbmeta/lpi/TELEDAT_2011_1_LANG_FR.pdf)).

I only used data for Switzerland but they seem to maintain global coverage:

[image]

I cannot comment on pricing and licensing of the product, but perhaps you could get a deal of getting access to admin boundaries only (which, if possible, could hopefully reduce the price).

Comment: Link appears to be broken

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in OSM then yes it is quite possible, I will suggest first download the [Osm planet file](http://planet.osm.org/).
Then extract only the administrative areas by using [Osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter#Getting_Tag_Statistics) and write subset of planet file which includes only administrative areas. After this use [QGIS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS_OSM_Plugin) or [Arcgis](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/) to extract administrative areas.
This whole process needs some time so before starting see OSM license first, if you are using this data commercially moreover coverage is different from country to country with some possible topological errors.

Second option is buy world set data from [GfK Geomarketing](http://www.gfk-geomarketing.com/en/digital_maps/map_features.html). 
Very nice coverage for the whole world. Approximate 255,545 feature for finest postal layer and 168,378 feature for finest administrative layer.

Topological corrected seamless coverage for the whole world. Data can be integrated in any system very easily as every layer in a country has an unique ID which is saved in metadata.

Data is available in all popular GIS formats.

See this image where i have used python to extract layer name and layer ID from a FileGeoDB format.[image]

Comment: The OSM data does not contain that much administrative areas. Usually it only contains the first administrative rank. The export can be easy made with the help of Geofabrik, like already mentioned by RajGovind.
The data by GfK Geomarketing is perfect but costs 40,000 €, which is way to much.

Comment: Yes there cost is high but if you are looking for most update world set data then I think it will cost you that much. 
As you have mention that GADM data is nearly perfect that means you do not need finest layer. First decide which level you need from every country and then ask the price for only these levels. World set will defiantly cost you more.

Comment: @Gideon OSM really has lots of administrative borders. Of course the completeness varies from country to country but for many regions they have become very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Geofabrik's free download server. This server has data extracts from the OpenStreetMap project which are normally updated every day. So that its better to collect world boundary  following link, If its suitable for your company you can use this link.

http://download.geofabrik.de/

Answer (score -1):

You can find detailed administrative divisions at http://www.diva-gis.org/.

cheers!
Rok

Comment: Thank you! Sadly their data set for administrative boundaries is also the one from GADM.