# OpenStreetMap - only administrative regions

Tags: openstreetmap

I'd need to display a map that shows only administrative regions level 1 for whole world. Is this doable with OpenStreetMap? I don't want any other data like roads, topology or similar to bi visible - only boundaries of administrative regions.

I'm new to GIS, so any guidelines will be helpful.

Project is commercial, so I'd need something that's free for commercial use.

Comment: Similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49099/where-can-i-get-a-world-map-with-boundaries-of-regions-and-communities-for-comme

Comment: Natural Earth http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this webservice by imagico.de:

http://www.imagico.de/map/boundaries_download_en.php

They offer boundaries as shapefile, based on OSM data.

If you want boundaries for only a few countries and maybe also its inner boundaries, have a look at https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/ ... there you can choose one or more boundaries and export in different formats.

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/